# getting the top 2 values of a list

Tags: python, pandas

In the below dataframe I have a list of values, how can we get the top 2 repeated from a list ?

DataFrame:

```
user    pro
A   [AA,AA,AA,BB,CC,AA,AA,CC,CC,BB]
B   [AA, BB, EE,BB,BB,EE,AA,CC,BB,EE]
C   [EE,EE,EE,CC,CC,CC,CC,DD,DD,AA]
D   [DD,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,BB,BB,BB]
```

Expected output:

```
A   [AA,CC]
B   [BB,EE]
C   [CC,EE]
D   [AA,BB]
```

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: yes, Am using pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
from collections import Counter

df['new']  = df['pro'].apply(lambda x: [k for k, v in Counter(x).most_common(2)])
print (df)
  user                                       pro       new
0    A  [AA, AA, AA, BB, CC, AA, AA, CC, CC, BB]  [AA, CC]
1    B  [AA, BB, EE, BB, BB, EE, AA, CC, BB, EE]  [BB, EE]
2    C  [EE, EE, EE, CC, CC, CC, CC, DD, DD, AA]  [CC, EE]
3    D      [DD, AA, AA, AA, AA, AA, BB, BB, BB]  [AA, BB]
```

Thanks @jpp:

```
df['common'] = [list(zip(*d.most_common(2)))[0] for d in df['pro'].map(Counter)]
```

Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:

```
df['common'] = df.pro.map(lambda x: [k for k, v in Counter(x).most_common(2)])
```

Comment: Alternative syntax (if you're doing a list comprehension you might not want `apply` too): `df['common'] = [list(zip(*d.most_common(2)))[0] for d in df['pro'].map(Counter)]`

Comment: You could combine the two and do `df.pro.map(lambda x: [k for k, v in Counter(x).most_common(2)])`

Answer (score 0):

Not being aware about [collections.Counter.most_common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) I came up with:

```
from collections import Counter
df['result'] = df['pro'].apply(lambda x: [i[0] for i in sorted(Counter(x).items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])[:2]])
```